# The end of a string is truncated when changed in Qml via Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Any time I would try changing any string in QML via Javascript the end of that string is truncated. Here is an example of a basic program I've written in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {

    //setup
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 250
    visible: true

    Button{
        id:toggle
        property bool buttonOn: false

        anchors.fill: parent

        Component.onCompleted: {
            toggle.text = "Activate"
        }

        onClicked: {
            buttonOn =! buttonOn;
            if(buttonOn){
                toggle.text = "Deactivate"
            }else{
                toggle.text = "Activate"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, when running, the code looks like this:
[image: 1]

And when I click the Button it looks like this:
[image: 2]

This doesn't seem to happen when it's set using pure QML like:

```
text: "Activate"
```

It also depends on how simmilar the words are, for instance id I were to use "button off" and "button on", this wouldn't happen.

I have no idea what could possible cause this and any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit:

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Qt but it doesn't do anything, and a simmilar problem exists with menuBars, where nothing is displayed in the right place.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this using the code you've attached. I could see that "Activate" and "Deactivate" are shown in full.  I'm on a MacOS, so it might be a Windows-specific thing (I'm guessing you use Windows from the window title bar).

Answer (score 1):

Try `QtQuick.Controls 2.2` I did test with that version and works fine for me. Also I'm working on Debian I don't know if that may be a problem.

As you can see I add a longer text and there is the result.

[image: Example in Linux]

**Edit 2** On a virtual windows 7 works fine. You should try to use another OS or something like that
[image: Example on Windows 7]

Comment: I'm going to try this on Windows 10, 'cause I'm suspecting that is a SO related issue...

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem is not reproducible (or at least with the info you've provided). Maybe you could force the problematic component not to truncate the text by using the `elide` property on the content item. However, this would only be a workaround and not a real solution to your problem.

Look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#elide-prop) for the `elide` property, and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button) for the customization of the `Button` item.